# Add a class to an object using javascript for specific querystring

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

I want to use javascript or jquery to add a class to an object based on the URL query string.

So if the url is `example.com/?var=1` then I want to add a new class to the object 
`#mydiv`

This would then be repeated for `?var=2`, `?var=3` and so on.

Here is what I have tried. The hope for this is that it would add a different class to the object if the query string was either `?var=2` or`?var=3`

```
var queryString = window.location.search.substr(1); 

switch (queryString) {
    case "2": document.getElementById('mydiv').className = 'newclass2';
;
                   break;
    case "3": document.getElementById('mydiv').className = 'newclass2';
;
                     break;
  }
```

EDIT:

It almost works now....

Here is my current code:

```
<script>
 var queryString = window.location.search.substr(1);
 var variant = queryString.split('=')[1];
 switch(variant) {
    case "stnl2": document.getElementById('getexclusive-sb').className = 'stnlvar2';
;
break;
    case "stnl3": document.getElementById('getexclusive-sb').className = 'stnlvar3';
;
break;
  }
</script>
```

It works if the url is "/?v=stnl2"

However Google content adds more to the url such as "?v=stnl2&utm_expid=42387987-0.dmsadhasjkdjasgdjgas-Q.4"

Is there a way for me to ignore the & and all details after so my code still works?

Comment: Yeah, ok. You can use one or the other.

Comment: Any help Sergio? I know this should be simple.

Comment: You start first and then we'll help.

Comment: @ForestParks As stated in the FAQ, questions asking for code to help should at least show what attempts the user has made by themselves.

Comment: That's why I got a downvote! Sorry. Modifying original question now.

Comment: Edited with the code I am trying to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var getUrlVars = function(){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    if(vars[0] == window.location.href){
        vars =[];
    }
    return vars;
}
var params = getUrlVars();
switch (params['var']){
...
}
```

Your params will have all the parameters from your query string. just past the variable name as a string and you will get the value of that parameter.

Comment: That's working for me now. Thank you.... I am guessing this only works if the var parameter appears first in the URL?

Comment: No it can work for anything .. for ex if ur parameter name is abc then u ve to get params['abc'] .. this will give u value of abc parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you tried has two issues.

**First**, you are getting the number of variant incorrectly. With your code, `queryString` will be  like `"var=2"`. So if you want only number, you should also split it by `=`:

```
 var queryString = window.location.search.substr(1);
 var variant = queryString.split('=')[1];
 switch(variant) {
     // ...
 }
```

*Note that this still actually doesn't check the **name** of your parameter, i.e. `var=`. If it is the only parameter, it would work. Otherwise, for proper handling of query string in JS you might want to look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/901115/693538)*

**Second**, look attentively into your `switch`. Both branches are actually identical, so they would do exactly the same regardless of queryString. Seems like you copy-pasted it unintentionally.

**UPD:**

As a said in my original answer, I just pointed you to some issues in your solution and how to fix them. It would not work if there is more than one parameter. Of course, you can just ignore all the string after `&`. But still there would be many cases in which it still won't work: what if your parameter is not the first?

I think it is not a good idea to make such assumptions, so we come to what I said previously: you might need proper, full-fledged parsing of parameters. [The link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/901115/693538) that I mentioned provides *A LOT* of solutions for this particular task, you may choose any of them. Another option is to use some existing library which have such function provided. That question and some other SO questions pointed me to these two:

- [jquery.parsequery](https://github.com/sousk/jquery.parsequery) — a jQuery plugin for this only purpose, with which you can do `variant = $.query(location).get("paramName")`. Seems to be old and not updated.
- [jsurl](https://github.com/Mikhus/jsurl) — a library for making different things with URLs, in particular, you can do `variant = (new Url).query.paramName` with it.

*NB: (replace `paramName` with your actual parameter name, `v` or `var` or whatever)*

Of course there could be some other good libs for it, also try googling on your own.

Comment: Thank you. The name isn't too important as I am just trying to style different variations for a Google experiement.

So now it almost works but...

Comment: Ok, I added more to the above question. Thanks for your help so far, it's almost working.

Comment: @ForestParks That is what I meant by saying that it would work only if there is only one parameter. Follow the link in my answer to a SO question which offers LOTS of various solutions for getting the parameter from query string by its name. I also updated my answer and added some more links.

Comment: Thanks. I am fairly new to javascript so honestly having real trouble wrapping my head around it... Still trying though.

Comment: In this case my "v=stnlvar2" or whatever will always be the first parameter because the Google experiment is set up to redirect to these variations and then it adds it's own stuff after the &... So is there an easy way for now to ignore the & and everything after?

Comment: @ForestParks Well you may do it just like you did with `=`: split by & and get first part, something like `queryString.split('&')[0]`. But I strongly discourage from using this, because correct URLs would still break your logic, and this may cause a lot of pain in later debugging. Do look the links I provided, there are the simple solutions as well there.

Comment: Thanks for your help here. The answer from Harry seemed to do everything you suggested such as pull out the specific name and not rely on it being in a certain order either.